# How to enable horizontal scroll in iPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I am designing screens using jquery mobile.

I'm not able to scroll horizontally and i used the following meta tag for view port settings.

How to get the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the width of the div tag and then declare overflow scroll on the div:

```
<div style="width:200px; overflow:scroll" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are serious cross-platform short-falls with using overflow=scroll in a mobile environment. I have had success with implimenting iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

I know that iScroll works on iPhone and Android devices from my own testing.

Comment: From the way of his question I thought he wanted a simple solution :P

Comment: I brought-up iScroll because I know on Android that there is not any support for overflow: scroll (the extra content within the element is just clipped). I believe I've seen the same behavior on iPhone where you can't scroll an element with the css of overflow: scroll.

Comment: @EmiyaMuljomdao It works but only if you drag with two fingers. This was updated in iOS 5 to where you can scroll with a single finger.